# is there a method to extract noun-adjectives pair from sentence in french?

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, spacy

i have this bit of code to extract noun-adj pairs using spacy , but this code work perfectly for english and not french because in french we have difficulty to extract pair of noun-adj :

1-  la voiture est belle,grande et jolie. (CCONJ = "et" when we have many adjectives)
2-  le tableau qui est juste en dessous est grand et beau. (so we have a coreference here , we should associate grand et beau to "tableau"

i know that dependencymatcher in spacy are robust but in  my case , sometimes I have texts which are not cleaned since it is about the opinions of people... so we need to do this manually...

in the output we should have something like this :
{"voiture":["belle","grande","jolie"], "tableau":["beau","grand"]}

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load("fr_core_news_sm")
doc = nlp('la voiture est belle et jolie. le tableau qui est juste en dessous est grand ') 
noun_adj_pairs = {}
for chunk in doc.noun_chunks:
    adj = []
    noun = ""
    for tok in chunk:
        if tok.pos_ == "NOUN":
           noun = tok.text
        if tok.pos_ == "ADJ" or tok.pos_ == "CCONJ":
           adj.append(tok.text)
    if noun:
        noun_adj_pairs.update({noun:" ".join(adj)})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote something by using `stanza` for high quality dependency parsing. It should not be a lot of work to convert this to spaCy if you need that specifically. Recursion is needed if you need to find embedded structures. Note that this specifically works for such constructions where an adjective is the parent of the subject that you are interested in and not for adjectival positions. E.g., this will not find adjectives like *La belle voiture*.

```py
import stanza

nlp = stanza.Pipeline("fr")

doc = nlp("La voiture est belle et jolie, et grand. Le tableau qui est juste en dessous est grand. La femme intelligente et belle est grande. Le service est rapide et les plats sont délicieux.")

def recursive_find_adjs(root, sent):
    children = [w for w in sent.words if w.head == root.id]

    if not children:
        return []

    filtered_c = [w for w in children if w.deprel == "conj" and w.upos == "ADJ"]
    # Do not include an adjective if it is the parent of a noun to prevent
    results = [w for w in filtered_c if not any(sub.head == w.id and sub.upos == "NOUN" for sub in sent.words)]
    for w in children:
        results += recursive_find_adjs(w, sent)

    return results

for sent in doc.sentences:
    nouns = [w for w in sent.words if w.upos == "NOUN"]
    noun_adj_pairs = {}
    for noun in nouns:
        # Find constructions in the form of "La voiture est belle"
        # In this scenario, the adjective is the parent of the noun
        cop_root = sent.words[noun.head-1]
        adjs = [cop_root] + recursive_find_adjs(cop_root, sent) if cop_root.upos == "ADJ" else []

        # Find constructions in the form of "La femme intelligente et belle"
        # Here, the adjectives are descendants of the noun
        mod_adjs = [w for w in sent.words if w.head == noun.id and w.upos == "ADJ"]
        # This should only be one element because conjunctions are hierarchical
        if mod_adjs:
            mod_adj = mod_adjs[0]
            adjs.extend([mod_adj] + recursive_find_adjs(mod_adj, sent))

        if adjs:
            unique_adjs = []
            unique_ids = set()
            for adj in adjs:
                if adj.id not in unique_ids:
                    unique_adjs.append(adj)
                    unique_ids.add(adj.id)

            noun_adj_pairs[noun.text] = " ".join([adj.text for adj in unique_adjs])

    print(noun_adj_pairs)
```

This will output:

```
{'voiture': 'belle jolie grand'}
{'tableau': 'grand'}
{'femme': 'grande belle intelligente'}
{'service': 'rapide', 'plats': 'délicieux'}
```

Comment: thank you very much  @Bram and you can help me if we want to display  the start_index and the stop_index of each word (noun and adjectives) please ?

Comment: You can get the word ID with `word.id`, but if you are asking about something else you should post a new question as it seems unrelated to this one specifically.

Comment: ok thank you and how can i add the case of "La belle voiture" ?

Comment: @Azizoue I edited my post. Note that this was *not* your initial question. In the future, only ask one question and do _not change that question_. Instead, ask a new question. Make sure that your initial question is as detailed as possible.

Comment: thank you very much ! it work perectly ! but just another note, how we can add the case of if we have "c'est magnifique et beau" we get in output {"vide" : "magnifique beau"}